# Cannibalizing just some of the resources of an rvalue ref

Tags: c++

My intent is the following: receive a rvalue reference (i.e. a reference to an object I want to cannibalize), remove **some** of its resources, and then return the other resources. I wrote this code:

```
std::vector<int> dosomething(std::vector<int> && vec) {
    // do something with vec (e.g. consume SOME of its resources)
    return std::move(vec);
}
```

but I'm not sure if:

1. is this the correct way to achieve what I want?
2. Should I use `std::forward` ? I believe not since this is no universal reference

Comment: @GillBates: No vector has been copied in the making of this question.

Comment: to be on the safe side, I would do:

std::vector<int> temp = std::move(vec);
return temp;

i believe this is correct way, but questions is kind of tricky.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nvm, I missed the `&&`.

Comment: @Nick Why would that be better than using the vector argument and then returning it as an rvalue?

Comment: I am not so experienced in C++. doing so, I know each step of the process (move, then rvo) and final code will be as fast as if you return std::move(vec); also probably temp variable will be optimized away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the `std::vector<int>` parameter is a placeholder for some more complex type, such as some `std::vector<Resource>`. You can't *move* an `int` and the only other resource you'd be able to acquire would be the data of the vector itself.

> 1. is this the correct way to achieve what I want?

Yes. If you omit the `std::move`, `vec` would be considered an lvalue and it would be copied onto the return.

You can observe this behaviour with this example:

```
struct C
{
    C() {}
    C( C const& ) { std::cout << "copy\n"; }
    C( C&& ) { std::cout << "move\n"; }
};

C f( C&& c )
{
    return std::move( c ); // cast to rvalue reference, invokes the move ctor
}

C g( C&& c )
{
    return c; // does not cast to rvalue reference, will invoke the copy ctor
}

int main()
{
    f( C{} ); // calling with rvalue, the return causes the move constructor to be called.
    g( C{} ); // calling with rvalue, but no std::move means calling the copy constructor.
}
```

> 2. Should I use std::forward ? I believe not since this is no universal reference

No. It wouldn't hurt since `std::forward<T>` conditionally casts (lvalues not be cast rvalue references, rvalues will be). However, it would basically achieve the same as `std::move` with more typing.

As a rule of thumb, you use `std::move` with rvalues and `std::forward<T>` with universal references.

Comment: is it OK to return function parameter? How RVO will work?

Comment: @Nick RVO will not be at play here because function parameters do not qualify for NRVO.

Comment: and this is why you need to `std::move`?

Comment: @Nick Yes, if you run my example, it shows exactly what happens when you don't use `std::move`... the copy constructor is called.

Answer (score 5):

> is this the correct way to achieve what I want?

OK, let's ignore the fact that `vector<int>` is not a type where it's reasonable to abscond with only some of its resources (it only has one resource: the allocation). I'll pretend you're talking about some type which actually has multiple resources.

I would consider such a function to be *misrepresenting* itself.

A function which declares that it takes a type as an rvalue reference is saying something *very important* about what it will do with that value. It is saying that it is going to either directly or indirectly perform movement of that object into another object of that type. It may do it itself, or it may call someone else who will. But that is what is going to happen before the function returns.

The idea is to make this code mean exactly what it says:

```
SomeFunction(std::move(value));
```

It looks like `value` is being moved into `SomeFunction`, just as surely as if you did `SomeType t = std::move(value);`. In both cases, the state of `value` should be moved-from. To do otherwise makes the code confusing.

A function which wishes to arbitrarily modify a parameter, leaving it in some new state, should take the parameter as a non-const *lvalue* reference, not an rvalue reference. Exactly what "modify" means is up to the function and what it needs to do. If you want to abscond with some resources and not others, you can do that with a non-const lvalue reference. You can even `std::move` from a subobject of a non-const lvalue reference. But you and your users should understand what the state of the object will be after the function call.

When you take a parameter by rvalue reference, that's shorthand for "when I return, this object will be in the moved-from state." Please don't misrepresent rvalue references as just non-const lvalue references.

Comment: I don't think there's any implicit contract that a function taking an r-value reference must actually move from the r-value? It's almost a stupid example, but for example `std::forward<T &&>(T &&)` doesn't actually move anything... and in general it's fine to refuse to move something. I think r-value just means, "you *can* move from it", not "you *must* move from it".

Comment: @Mehrdad: It depends on who you ask, but [the Core Guidelines seems to agree with me](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-consume). As for forwarding, that's a different matter, since it deals with reference collapsing and thus may or may not be moving the value depending on what the user passed.

Comment: But the entire premise there is that you're talking about a "consume" parameter in the first place, which basically by definition requires the entire parameter to be always consumed... but that assumption that isn't satisfied here. This use case doesn't fall into any of those categories as far as I can see.

Comment: @Mehrdad: "*but that assumption that isn't satisfied here.*" Yes. And therefore you shouldn't use syntax that looks exactly like "I'm going to consume this" if you *aren't going to consume it*. I don't see what the confusion here is.

Comment: Huh? The syntax to be used follows from the semantics you want, not the other way around. The guideline is saying, "*if* this is a 'consume' parameter, *then* you should pass it by `X &&` and `std::move` the parameter". It is ***not*** saying, "*if* you pass by `X &&`, then this is a consume parameter and you should `std::move` it". So it doesn't apply to this situation since the premise is not satisfied as this is *not* a 'consume' parameter.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The validity check for that rule says, "Flag all `X&&` parameters (where `X` is not a template type parameter name) where the function body uses them without std::move." The "all" there doesn't leave much room for debate.

Comment: Aren't you misreading it...? Doesn't "flag" just mean "this is a *potential* violation"? Like if you look at P.1 ("Express ideas directly in code"), it says "flag uses of casts"... but that doesn't mean every single cast implies you're not directly expressing your ideas directly in code. The way I'm reading it, they're saying, "*if* you want to enforce this rule, *then* blindly flag these use cases, and check them manually". I don't think they're saying "every flagged use is necessarily a violation of this rule".

Answer (score 3):

> My intent is the following: receive a rvalue reference (i.e. a reference to an object I want to cannibalize), remove some of its resources, and then return the other resources.

That's ok, but it's probably better to either:

- remove the resource placeholders completely, or
- replace the removed resources with other objects, or
- indicate to the caller which resources were removed

Because if you don't do one of these, then the user may use one of the moved-from items that you cannibalised. Since moved-from objects (at least in the STL) have 'valid but undefined' state, the use of these cannibalised objects will have undefined results.

You don't want that.

> is this the correct way to achieve what I want?

It seems fine

> Should I use std::forward ? I believe not since this is no universal reference

No, you shouldn't. Your reasoning is correct.

FYI: 'indicating to the users which resources were removed' has a model in the standard library. Have a look at `std::remove_if` - it actually moves the 'removed' items to the end of the sequence and returns an iterator with marks the `end` of the remaining items and the beginning of the 'removed' ones.

Here's one way I might approach the problem.

objective: do something with all strings lexically greater than "ccc" in a vector, leaving the rest in the vector in original order

```
template<class T>
void do_something_with(T t)
{
    std::cout << "did something with " << t << std::endl;
}

template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate>
ForwardIt rotate_if(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    while(first != last)
    {
        auto n = std::next(first);
        if (p(*first))
        {
            if (n != last) {
                std::rotate(first, n, last);
                first = n;
                last = std::prev(last);
            }
            else {
                last = first;
                break;
            }
        }
        first = n;
    }
    return last;
}
template<class T, class Pred, class Model>
std::vector<T> do_something_if(std::vector<T>&& in, Pred pred, Model&& model)
{
    auto result = std::move(in);
    auto ibreak = rotate_if(std::begin(result),
                                 std::end(result),
                                 [&](auto& v) {
                                     auto match = pred(v, model);
                                     return match;
                                 });
    for (auto i = ibreak ; i != std::end(result) ; ++i) {
        do_something_with(std::move(*i));
    }
    result.erase(ibreak, std::end(result));
    return result;
}

void test()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words = {
        "yyy",
        "aaa",
        "zzz",
        "bbb",
    };

    auto filtered = do_something_if(std::move(words), std::greater<>(), "ccc");

    std::cout << "remaining items:\n";
    for (auto& w : filtered) {
        std::cout << w << std::endl;
    }
}
```

expected output:

```
did something with zzz
did something with yyy
remaining items:
aaa
bbb
```

There will be more efficient solutions in most circumstances but this one avoids memory allocations.